# Can't get rid of this error: "app:processDebugResources"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

I already tried looking for an answer, found some, but none of them fixed my issue. I have no idea what I'm doing, I'm just trying to change some colors and icons, nothing to serious, never compiled something for Android before. What I'm trying to compile is: https://github.com/dkim0419/SoundRecorder. If I open it in Eclipse, Android Studio or just use the terminal to compile it, shouldn't it just compile? With no issues? I have my path set (my current path to Android SDK is /home/alex/Android/Sdk and NDK is /home/alex/Android/Ndk). I just can't get rid of it. I even tried creating **a blank test project** and tried to compile it and got the same error. Is there something very obvious and stupid that I am missing?

This is what happens when I try to build the application:

```
alex@alex-Aspire-1640:~/Code/SoundRecorder-master$ ./gradlew build
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72103Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72103Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library
:app:prepareComJpardogoMaterialtabstripLibrary106Library
:app:prepareComMelnykovFloatingactionbutton110Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
/home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/src/main/res/drawable/icon_web.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/alex/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /home/alex/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar -M /home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F   /home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.danielkim.soundrecorder -0 apk --output-text-symbols /home/alex/Code/SoundRecorder-master/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
     132


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 53.214 secs
```

Comment: ... what's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's an error? Is it in your LogCat? I don't think it's what you think it is... I could be mistaken.

Comment: Are you using rooted device or emulator?

Comment: I can't root my device, I haven't tried emulating it either. Didn't know you had to. How would I go about that? (I am really sorry, I am really new to this)

Comment: Is this project put together right? I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I tried to emulate it, nope. Nothing I do is making it work. Could someone else try compiling this (maybe with a little more expertise than me) and see if it works?